# Why do I get this error in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this **code:**

```
jQuery(window).scroll(function() {

     var scroll = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
     //scroll_break = parseInt($(".header-container").height());
     console.log( "pozitie scroll",scroll);
    // console.log( "scroll_break",scroll_break );


     var elem = $(".header-wrapper");
     if (elem.hasClass ("class")) {
         alert("sss");
      }else{
 alert("sssa");
      }
});
```

While I run this code receive the following error (I have attached a screenshot below to understand)

[image]

This is the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasClass' of null
```

From what this error occurs?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

I create a sample [here](https://jsfiddle.net/dn14ok0y/1/)

Comment: where have you declared `elem`? can you share your html as well?

Comment: can you share your html code?

Comment: There must be some other code involved. Can't even reproduce doing : `var elem=$();
alert(elem.hasClass('test'))//false;`.  Are you sure the variable `elem` hasn't been changed? Simple test `console.log(elem)`

Comment: I tried your code and didn't get your error, maybe you've got some other code, which is in conflict...

Comment: your error doesn't appear in your sample jsfiddle

Comment: Can't make demo break to reproduce the error. Your selector is invalid match and it still doesn't break. Inspect `elem` in your live code by logging to console...it isn't a jQuery object as you think and something not shown is affecting it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suspicion is that `$` may be being used elsewhere in the page by another library which is why you are using `jQuery(window)` and not `$(window)`

Try:

```
var elem = jQuery(".header-wrapper");
```

Answer (score 1):

That means that elem is not actually an element. I'm guessing that `.header-wrapper` is not an actual class that exists in your HTML

In your browser javascript console, typing in `$(".header-wrapper")` and hitting enter should return an array of all the elements that are matched so you can check it.

To be sure you don't get this error, you should change your if statement:

```
if (elem.length && elem.hasClass("class")) {
```

The `elem.length` part checks to see if it exists before you call .hasClass() on it.

Comment: I create a sample in jsdfidle

Answer (score 0):

Javascript thinks, you want to get a property of your `elem` variable. That is because you made a whitespace between function name and the `()` for the parameters. Remove it!

And the error message said, that `elem` is null, so the jquery selector in the line above didn't find anything. So look at your code, if there exists an element with the class `header-wrapper`.

```
jQuery(window).scroll(function() {

     var scroll = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
     console.log( "pozitie scroll",scroll);

     elem = $(".header-wrapper");
     if (elem.hasClass("class")) { //Without whitespace
         alert("sss");
      }else{
         alert("sssa");
      }
});
```

Comment: You don't need to remove the space.

Comment: jQuery fails silently when selector doesn't find a match

Comment: ok but why did not it work?
is a simple example ... should go smoothly

Comment: @cristi create a demo in jsfiddle.net that replicates it. Also what do you see when you log elem to console instead of calling `hasClass`

Answer (score 0):

can you post the html file as well. b'coz the js code is perfect there must be some issue with the html code some class name or something.